# How to AddFroce to a Rigidbody 2D on 1 screen-touch?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a simple android game in Unity 2D, I have to make our player jump by adding force or changing the velocity of its Rigidbody2D (I know how). The problem is I don't know how to tell unity that add force on single screen tap (I'm not familiar with touch inputs) so any help would be appreciated. Please keep it clean as I'm just a beginner.
Here's the script I made so far.

```
{
    public Rigidbody2D _playerRB;


    public bool _canMove;

    public float _speed;   //keep this above cam speed (relative)
    public float _jumpForce;


    void Start()
    {
        _playerRB = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }


    void Update()
    {
        _playerRB.velocity = new Vector2(_speed, _playerRB.velocity.y);

        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {


            _playerRB.velocity = new Vector2(_playerRB.velocity.x, _jumpForce);



        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Here’s an example script that shoots a ray whenever the user taps on the screen: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MobileInput.html Do you understand it?

Comment: @GabrielMota yep thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by handling the touch input in your Update function:

```
void Update()
{
    _playerRB.velocity = new Vector2(_speed, _playerRB.velocity.y);

    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            _playerRB.velocity = new Vector2(_playerRB.velocity.x, _jumpForce);
        }
    }

}
```

---

Also there are different `TouchPhases` such as `TouchPhase.Moved` which indicates that the touch input has moved and `TouchPhase.Ended` which indicates that the finger has stopped touching the screen. Using these in your `Update` you can achieve a lot with touch controls.